# Is there any readResolve/writeReplace equivalent for Room?

Tags: android, android-room

Whenever we read/write Object from disk, we can perform some Object modification via `readResolve`/`writeReplace`, before it is actual being read/written into disk.

Is there any readResolve/writeReplace equivalent for Andorid Room?

`TypeConverter` is pretty close. However, it only operated with single Object attribute, not the entire Object.

One of the use case is that, I have an Object with field String `body`.

- Before `body` field is committed, I would like the `encrypted(body)` to be written to DB. The original `body` value in Object itself is not being modified.
- When `body` field is being read from DB, I would like `decrypted(body)` being read from DB. The original `encrypted body` value in DB is not being modified.

Comment: Room itself does not support this, at least at present. IMHO, Room entities are DTOs, so the encryption/decryption would happen when you convert the entities into model objects, where the entities hold the encrypted data (`byte[]`, presumably) and the model objects hold the decrypted data.